# DocuSign - Granting Consent - Redirect URI Variable

Tags: docusignapi

I have been following the DocuSign documentation to have a user "grant consent" for an application to user a DocuSign user account. I got that working. Now I am trying to make some adjustments to the url that sends a user to DocuSign, and then redirects the user back to my application.

**This works for me right now:**
https://account-d.docusign.com/oauth/auth?response_type=code&scope=impersonation&client_id=XXXXXX&redirect_uri=http://localhost:8080/DocuSignCallBack

**What is want to do:**
https://account-d.docusign.com/oauth/auth?response_type=code&scope=impersonation&client_id=XXXXXX&redirect_uri=http://localhost:8080/DocuSignCallBack?variableName=ABC123
(Where 'ABC123' is dynamic)

In short - I want to pass a dynamic value in the redirect URL so that when I get the callback, I still have the value. **My problem:** When try to pass the variable, it doesn't work. DocuSign complains that the Redirect URL isn't configured - so I adjusted the DocuSign Redirect URL for that client to include the '?variableName=' on the end - I got the same error.

**My Question:** Can I pass a dynamic value to DocuSign in the redirect_uri, and get that value back when I receive the callback? How can I adjust the configuration at DocuSign to allow a variable in the URL?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You `cannot pass dynamic variable` in redirect_uri, it should exactly match what has been configured in your IntegratorKey. To pass anything dynamic, you can use `state` parameter, whatever value you will set in `state` while calling DocuSign URL, DocuSign will pass exactly same value in the response after authenticating the user in the response. The Request URL may look like below:

```
https://account-d.docusign.com/oauth/auth?response_type=code&scope=impersonation&client_id=XXXXXX&redirect_uri=http://localhost:8080/DocuSignCallBack&state=variableName_ABC123
```

Treat this `state` parameter for the dynamic variable.

Comment: This is exactly what I needed. The URL you suggested worked perfectly. Thanks!